# How do I get a random word from a list from a text file?

Tags: python

```
import random

with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            LIST = []
            LIST.append(word)
answer = random.choice(LIST)

print(answer)
```

My text file consists of a few words and the last word in the text file is always chosen as answer. The words in the text file are split by spaces. Am I splitting the text wrong? How do I get a random word from the list?

Comment: Are you sure that `LIST` contains all the words?  Hint: it does not. Try tracing the execution in a debugger or on paper to understand why.

Comment: LIST = [] should be before he for loop.  The current way it will only have the last word in the line.

Comment: It's because you are making the list empty everytime, make it outside of the loop

Comment: It's not the last word actually it's the last list you made

Comment: move LIST = [] outside of the loop & it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working

```
import random

LIST = []
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            LIST.append(word)
answer = random.choice(LIST)

print(answer)
```

You were creating the list every time, so it returned the last list you've created

Answer (score 0):

Try this more optimized solution instead of creating multiple loops

```
import random
LIST=[]
with open('samplefile.txt','r') as f:
    LIST=f.read().split()
answer = random.choice(LIST)
print(answer)
```

For Your solution you just need to put LIST=[]  outside of loop

```
import random
LIST = []
with open('samplefile.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            LIST.append(word)
answer = random.choice(LIST)

print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the list inside the loop for every time you read a line and this causes the list get truncated and at the end holds just one value in it. BTW, don't use Python method names for your variables.

Try this:

```py
import random

myList = list()
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for myWord in line.split():
            myList.append(myWord)

answer = random.choice(myList)

print(answer)
```